# django-admin.py and virtualenv issue on Windows

Tags: python, windows, django, django-admin, virtualenv

In my system there is Django 1.2.3 installed system wide:

```
C:\>python -c "import django; print django.get_version()"
1.2.3
C:\>django-admin.py --version
1.2.3
```

Then there is a virtual environment called *venv* in C:\dev where I installed Django 1.2.4:

```
C:\> dev\venv\Scripts\activate.bat
(venv) C:\> python -c "import django; print django.get_version()"
1.2.4
(venv) C:\> django-admin.py --version
1.2.3
```

My questions:

1. Why django-admin.py reports version 1.2.3, if the current Python (virtual) environment has django 1.2.4 installed?
2. How can I use Django's 1.2.4 django-admin.py automatically when *venv* is active?

Additional info:

- virtualenv version: 1.5.1, Python version 2.7
- command used to create *venv*: `C:\dev\> virtualenv --no-site-packages venv`
- `(venv) C:\> echo %PATH%`

  `C:\dev\venv\Scripts; ...other paths...`
- shebang of django-admin.py in *venv*: `#!C:\dev\Scripts\python.exe`

Hope you can help, many thanks.

Comment: hi, i had similair problem on linux when I tried to use an *already exisiting django project* with a *later installed* virtualenv.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is because your windows has associated `.py` extension with the globally installed `python.exe`. Therefore when you type `django-admin.py`, even though you're in a virtualenv, the global python is invoked, and it in turn finds your global django installation in its own site-packages. Try `python django-admin.py` to circumvent the association.

Answer (score 16):

As shanyu already explained, it is because of *.py file associations made to your Python install executable instead of your virtualenv. However, to answer your second question differently, I solved this problem by creating a `django-admin.bat` in my virtualenv's `Scripts` directory. Its contents?

```
@echo off
python %VIRTUAL_ENV%\Scripts\django-admin.py %*
```

Now you can use `django-admin startproject <project_name>`. The necessary `PATH` and `VIRTUAL_ENV` environment variables should have already been set correctly by virtualenv when you activated the environment.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on linux when I tried to use an *already exisiting django project* with a *later installed* virtualenv.

Is it possible that django-admin.py of django 1.2.4 is **not** on your path but that django-admin.py of your django 1.2.3 install is?

That would explain your output from

```
C:\> dev\venv\Scripts\activate.bat
(venv) C:\> python -c "import django; print django.get_version()"
1.2.4
(venv) C:\> django-admin.py --version
1.2.3
```

because the `python` command is on the path of your virtualenv but the `django-admin.py` file might not be.

As to your second question (assuming my guess above is correct): sym-link the `django-admin.py` file into your `C:\dev\venv\Scripts` directory, although I am not sure how that works on windows (are you using Cygwin?).

Of course you can always call it as `python C:\path\to\django-admin.py` (since the right python version is called) but of course that is a lot of typing.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I'm on plain Windows (no Cygwin). django-admin.py *is* on system path, as shown in point 3 of additional info in my oririnal post. C:\dev\venv\Scripts placed as first path _should_ override system wide Scripts directory (but it doesn't seem so!)

Comment: Hi, ok is the shebang line `#!C:\dev\Scripts\python` pointing to the correct python version? It seems it might need to be `#!C:\dev\venv\Scripts\python`, but I am guessing here.

Comment: You are right, it should have been #!C:\dev\venv\Scripts\python, sorry it was an error in transcription. Btw, shanyu gave a realistic explanation for the issue ;-(

Answer (score 1):

I just typed **django-admin**, without the .py file extension, and worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had to point the "global python.exe" to my virtualenv in my project so I created my own activate.cmd

```
set THE_PATH=c:\my-envs\my-specific-env\Scripts
ftype Python.File="%THE_PATH%\python.exe" %%1 %%*
%THE_PATH%\activate.bat
```

It changes the the file type association using windows command 'ftype'.

Answer (score 0):

i used Philip Nelson's solution but had to add quotes for spaces in my filename:

python "%VIRTUAL_ENV%\Scripts\django-admin.py" %*