# Python + Django + Virtualenv importing django.core failed

Tags: python, django, path, virtualenv

I'm using Python 2.7.3 on Windows 7.
I've set PATH as a `C:\python27` which is a original python binary path.

First, I made a new Virtualenv named "django" without any options,

```
virtualenv django
```

Second, activated Virtualenv,

```
c:\workspace\py-envs\django\Scripts\activate
```

Third, installed Django by using pip,

```
pip install django
```

Fourth, just executed `django-admin.py startproject SOME_NAME` like below.

Then, I faced an issue while importing `django.core` package.

FAILED

```
(django) c:\workspace\python>django-admin.py startproject a
(django) c:\workspace\python>python django-admin.py startproject a
(django) c:\workspace\python>c:\py-envs\django\Scripts\python django-admin.py startproject a
```

ERROR message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\workspace\py-envs\django\Scripts\django-admin.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.core import management
ImportError: No module named django.core
```

WORKED

```
(django) c:\workspace\python>python c:\py-envs\django\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject a
```

CHECKED

- `django-admin.py` exists in `c:\py-envs\django\Scripts\`
- virtualenv added `C:\py-envs\django\Scripts\` line in PATH (checked with echo %PATH%)
- `pip freeze` result only shows Django==1.5

I'd like to start a project by using the first command:

```
python django-admin.py startproject a
```

What else I can do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [django-admin.py and virtualenv issue on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837632/django-admin-py-and-virtualenv-issue-on-windows)

Comment: @LieRyan Unfortunately, I haven't installed Django on normal environment. I only installed on my virtual env. I also checked that normal env didn't have django-admin.py file in \Scripts folder and virtualenv shows proper version number.

Answer (score 2):

**Under a virtual environment** (virtualenv), the only default way to call `django-admin` is to call it by `django-admin.py`.

The following works:

- `django-admin.py startproject PROJECT_NAME`,

The following doesn't:

- `django-admin startproject PROJECT_NAME`,
- `python django-admin startproject PROJECT_NAME`,
- `python django-admin.py startproject PROJECT_NAME`.

Answer (score 1):

This happen because the windows python interpreter use the global interpreter always and not the current python virtualenv interpreter.

Example:
C:\python27\python.exe # windows always use it

and not this

C:\envs\my_env\Scripts\python.exe

In oficial documentation, I found this:
http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html?highlight=#-m
"When called with -m module-name, the given module is located on the Python module path and executed as a script."

if you type in console, echo %PATH%, will see the virtualenv path in first. Therefore

```
(django) c:\workspace\python>python -m django-admin startproject my_new_project
```

should work