# python django-herokuapp on windows error : The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, django, heroku

On windows 7 32-bits Python2.7, I can't use the commands 'manage.py herokuapp'. I get an error about a missing file? Could you drive me how to debug that please?

```
d:\myproject>venv\Scripts\activate.bat
(venv) d:\myproject>echo %PYTHONPATH%
;d:\myproject\venv\Lib\site-packages\herokuapp

(venv) d:\myproject>python manage.py herokuapp deploy
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

(venv) d:\myproject>python --version
Python 2.7.2
```

Update after comment of Daniel

I added `ftype Python.File="%VIRTUAL_ENV%\Scripts\python.exe" %1 %*` at the beginning of  activate.bat. but it didn't fix the problem.
This problem occurs with every commands starting by `manage.py herokuapp`

Comment: Checkout the question and answers here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837632/django-admin-py-and-virtualenv-issue-on-windows/14193933#14193933
http://stackoverflow.com/a/14193933/1714030

Comment: Thanks Daniel I'm gonna try that tonight. I'll keep you in touch.

Comment: Daniel, it didnt work as expected but it was worth a try. I updated the question.